# using IEEEtran document class -how to format three authors using IEEEtran

Tags: titles, ieeetran

I am using IEEE Transactions conference class

\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}

How I should align the author properly so that it appears in this format?

```
         title
author1        author2
        author3
```

can't attach an image because of low reputation,sorry for this:(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can type code like this

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    \title{title}   
    \author{author1 & & author2 \\ & author3}   
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

it will produce,

[image]